# bash 'while read line' efficiency with big file

Tags: bash, performance

I was using a while loop to process a task,

which read records from a big file about 10 million lines.

I found that the processing become more and more slower as time goes by.

and I make a simulated script with 1 million lines as blow, which reveal the problem.

but I still don't know why, how does the `read` command work?

```
seq 1000000 > seq.dat
while read s;
do
    if [ `expr $s % 50000` -eq 0 ];then
        echo -n $( expr `date +%s` - $A) ' ';
        A=`date +%s`;
    fi
done < seq.dat
```

The terminal outputs the time interval:

98  98  98  98  98  97  98  97  98  101  106  112  121  121  127  132  135  134

at about 50,000 lines,the processing become slower obviously.

Comment: awk will be much faster for this task.

Comment: very nice test case! would help to visualize the problem by adding the value `$s` to your output. Seems like you know your testing, but I'll ask the obvious, 1. are there other processes that may be competing for resources? 2. have you run this multiple times and you're getting the same results? I'll try this in my environment and if I get something different, I'll add my input. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your code, I saw the same pattern of increasing times (right from the beginning!). If you want faster processing, you should rewrite using shell internal features. Here's my bash version:

```
tabChar="   "  # put a real tab char here, of course
seq 1000000 > seq.dat
while read s;
do
    if (( ! ( s % 50000 ) )) ;then
        echo $s "${tabChar}" $( expr `date +%s` - $A) 
        A=$(date +%s);
    fi
done < seq.dat
```

**edit**
fixed bug, output indicated each line was being processed, now only every 50000'th line gets the timing treatment. Doah!

was

```
  if ((  s % 50000 )) ;then
```

fixed to

```
  if (( ! ( s % 50000 ) )) ;then
```

**output now `echo ${.sh.version} =` Version JM 93t+ 2010-05-24**

```
50000
100000   1
150000   0
200000   1
250000   0
300000   1
350000   0
400000   1
450000   0
500000   1
550000   0
600000   1
650000   0
700000   1
750000   0
```

**output bash**

```
50000    480
100000   3
150000   2
200000   3
250000   3
300000   2
350000   3
400000   3
450000   2
500000   2
550000   3
600000   2
650000   2
700000   3
750000   3
800000   2
850000   2
900000   3
950000   2
800000   1
850000   0
900000   1
950000   0
1e+06    1
```

As to why your original test case is taking so long ... not sure. I was surprised to see both the time for each test cyle AND the increase in time. If you really need to understand this, you may need to spend time instrumenting more test stuff. Maybe you'd see something running `truss` or `strace` (depending on  your base OS).

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's probably because using `expr` means firing up a separate process each time you want to do math.  Specifically it fires it up for that `if` statement for every single number.  As you've shown using built-in evaluation is substantially faster.  Though that doesn't explain the increase in time.  +1 for finding the root of the issue rather than assuming it was `read`, as I did.

Comment: Thanks， I found that was not a 'read' issue. Using ((  )) instead of 'expr' is far more fast than my original script, and I  added a pid print

Comment: Thanks， I found that was not a 'read' issue. Using ((  )) instead of 'expr' is far more fast than my original script, and I added a pid print in my process , finding that pid number increasing. May it be the reason why the script slow down? What happened while the os ran out of its pid?

Comment: The processes being created have a very short life. Different OS's handle pid #s differnt ways. Some increase 1 + 1, some are chosen randomly from an available pid-pool. I don't think pids are your problem, but to answer your question 'what happens when the OS runs out of pids?', my guess would be that you get an OS level error message like "can't create process". Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: You can use `$'\t'` for a real tab character.

Answer (score 4):

Read is a comparatively slow process, as the author of "Learning the Korn Shell" [points out](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch07_02.htm#KSH-CH-7-SECT-2.2)*.  (Just above Section 7.2.2.1.)  There are other programs, such as `awk` or `sed` that have been highly optimized to do what is essentially the same thing: read from a file one line at a time and perform some operations using that input.

Not to mention, that you're calling an external process every time you're doing subtraction or taking the modulus, which can get expensive.  `awk` has both of those functionalities built in.

As the following test points out, `awk` is quite a bit faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

seq 1000000 | 
awk '
  BEGIN {
    command = "date +%s"
    prevTime = 0
  }
  $1 % 50000 == 0 {
    command | getline currentTime
    close(command)

    print currentTime - prevTime
    prevTime = currentTime
  }
'
```

Output:

```
1335629268
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
1   
0   
0   
0   
0
```

Note that the first number is equivalent to `date +%s`.  Just like in your test case, I let the first match be.

***Note***

*Yes the author is talking about the Korn Shell, not bash as the OP tagged, but bash and ksh are rather similar in a lot of ways.  ksh is actually a superset of bash.  So I would assume that the read command is not drastically different from one shell to another.

Comment: The comment in that book applies to older Korn Shells. Ksh  remains in continuous development, and I don't think this applies to newer kornshell (as much anyway). `echo ${.sh.version}` to find your version. AND of course, OP has flagged this as a `bash` issue. But, yes read is slower, the test has lots of extra subprocesses, but it is the same set of processes running on each iteration. Depending on real problem, awk is likely much better for processing large files. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Added a little blurb about ksh and bash.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: my point is that `read` in older kshs was pretty darn slow. It got mostly fixed, but as I'm running essentially same code now between new ksh and bash 3.2, bash is slightly faster ;-( (my ksh bias is now showing).

Comment: @shellter Ah, I didn't know that.  I've only been doing serious shell scripting for a year an a half now, and I've always used pretty recent versions, so I have no idea what older versions of ksh are like.

Comment: as you point out, `read` isn't the problem! Going out for the day, will check back tonight. Good luck to all.